# How to use Float32MultiArray (Publisher)

Tags: python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to write a python code using the Float32MultiArray to run my robot's motors.

The code is below:

```
motor = rospy.Publisher('encoder', Float32MultiArray, queue_size = 2)

while not rospy is shutdown():
   
    arg = Float32MultiArray()
    arg.layout.dim[0].label ="x"
    arg.layout.dim[0].size = 1
    arg.layout.dim[0].stride = 1
   
    arg.layout.dim[1].label ="y"
    arg.layout.dim[1].size = 1
    arg.layout.dim[1].stride = 1
    
    arg.layout.data_offset = 1
    arg.data = [100, 100]

    motor.publish(arg)
```

However, I have the error below:

```
TypeError: Invalid number of arguments, arg should be ['layout','data'] args are(0.0)
```

Could you please help me ?

Thank you in advance,

Shanika

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324541/how-to-use-float32multiarray-(publisher)/) by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-06-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to allocate the arrays, when you're trying to access dim[] and data[] you haven't yet allocated it to have any size or inserted something into it.

E.i.

```
thing = MultiArrayDimension()
thing.label = "x"
thing.size = 1
thing.stride = 1
arg.layout.dim.append(thing)
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on 2019-06-04**:
Thank you, I will try this right now

**Comment by [wydmynd](https://answers.ros.org/users/40443/wydmynd/) on 2020-10-21**:
I looked a long time for this information